# Converting 24hour time to 12hour time?

Tags: java, android, date

Hello I am using an android application and I am trying to figure out how to convert a 24 hour time to a 12hour time.

```
Example 
24 hour format 12:18:00

to 
12 hour format 12:18pm
```

Comment: Actually, that should be 12:18pm. :)

Comment: How are you getting this time value? Plain string? date/time/object? timestamp?

Comment: plain text, sorry that i didnt state it format is in 12:18:00

Comment: btw ted :O edited, my mistake

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String s = "12:18:00";
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //HH for hour of the day (0 - 23)
Date d = f1.parse(s);
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
f2.format(d).toLowerCase(); // "12:18am"
```

Comment: make sure you are writing h not H

Comment: There is a bug while converting 12:00noon. Both AM and PM is reported as AM when the time is between 12:00 and 12:59

Comment: Any fix for bug that Magesh mentioned?

Comment: Yaa.. To fix the bug, use `DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: FYI, the classes shown here are poorly-designed and troublesome, now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8 or 9 you can use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library like this :

```
String time = "22:18:00";
String result = LocalTime.parse(time).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma"));
```

---

**Output**

```
10:18PM
```

Comment: This is the modern way and the recommended one in 2018. On not-brand-new Android it works too when you add ThreeTenABP to your Android project and make sure you import the date-time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages. See [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. happy to hear all this information, always learn from you

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely need to take a look at Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To display the data in the format you want you should use something like this:

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
   sdf.format(dateObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat but note that HH is different from hh.

Say we have a time of 18:20

The format below would return 18:20 PM

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
```

While this format would return 6:20 PM

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
final String timein24Format = "22:10";

try {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(timein24Format );
    String timein12Format=new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
     String s= time ;

     DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
     Date d = null;
        try {
             d = f1.parse(s);
             DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
             time = f2.format(d).toUpperCase(); // "12:18am"

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```